useEffect Not Properly Handling Focus on iOS Devices in React Application
I'm working on a React application where we use a custom hook (useFlipAnimation) to manage the flipping animation of a card component. When the card flips to its back side, we want to automatically focus on a textarea element for input. This functionality works as expected on Android devices and web browsers, but we encounter issues on iOS devices where the automatic focus does not occur.
Code Overview:
We determine the initial side of the card and use a useEffect hook to manage focus based on the card's current side (front or back) and whether it is currently flipping (isFlipping). When the card flips to the back (side === 'back') and is not flipping (!isFlipping), we attempt to focus on the textarea by calling handleFocusMessage. Conversely, we call handleFocusOutMessage to remove focus otherwise.
useEffect(() => {
  if (side === 'back' && !isFlipping) {
    handleFocusMessage(); // Supposed to focus on the textarea
  } else {
    handleFocusOutMessage(); // Removes focus
  }
}, [side, isFlipping, handleFocusMessage, handleFocusOutMessage]);

//handle focus

  const handleFocusMessage = useCallback(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      const input = messageInputRef.current;
      input.focus();
      if (input?.value) {
        const length = input.value.length;
        input.setSelectionRange(length, length);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocusOutMessage = useCallback(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      const input = messageInputRef.current;
      input.blur();
    }
  }, []);


  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);

  <MessageInput
                id={'message-input'}
                data-testid={'message-input'}
                ref={messageInputRef}
                value={text}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                maxLength={150}
              />


//style

const MessageInput = styled.textarea`
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px !important;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  z-index: 80;
`;

The handleFocusMessage function is intended to set focus on a textarea element within the card. This setup works flawlessly in Android and desktop web environments but fails on iOS devices.
Issue Details:

The autofocus functionality is triggered upon the completion of the flip animation.
This issue only occurs on iOS devices; both Android and web environments perform as expected.
Debugging logs confirm that the respective handleFocusMessage and handleFocusOutMessage functions are called at the correct times.

Questions:

Are there known limitations or security features in iOS that prevent programmatic focus from being set under certain conditions that might be affecting this behavior?
Is there a recommended approach or workaround for ensuring consistent focus behavior across all devices, particularly for dynamic content like this where focus is set following an animation or state change rather than direct user interaction?

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
Attempted Solutions:

Ensuring that the focus logic is not hindered by asynchronous state updates.
Directly setting focus on the textarea element using vanilla JavaScript outside the React lifecycle (this approach also inconsistently works on iOS).
Considering the possibility that iOS requires a user interaction to trigger focus, I attempted to refactor the interaction model to accommodate this, but due to the nature of the functionality (automatic focus post-animation), this solution is not viable.

